# Is there an “after” keyword in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.6.x

This is to avoid any further question in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These keywords are reserved in Solidity. They might become part of the syntax in the future. Check this [link](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.6/miscellaneous.html#reserved-keywords)